# WebSphere Portal Theme: Access page metadata

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am trying to fetch the page metadata using JSP file. I am using below code to fetch the page metadata.

```
<%!
    public void testMeta(PageContext pageContext, String nodeId) {
        Map<String, Object> parentMeta = (Map<String, Object>)pageContext.getAttribute(nodeId, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
        //System.out.println("Meta Object " + nodeId + ": " + parentMeta);
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entry1 = parentMeta.entrySet();
        //System.out.println("No. of elements: " + entry1.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: entry1 ) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
        Set<String> keySet = parentMeta.keySet();
        if (keySet != null ){
            System.out.println("Keyset contains something");
        } else {
            //System.out.println("Keyset is NULL");
        }
    }
%>

<c:if test="${empty parentID}">
    <c:set var="parentID" value="${param.parentID}" />
</c:if>
<c:set var="showHidden" value="${param.showHidden}" />
<c:set var="parentNode" value="${wp.navigationModel[parentID]}"/>
<c:if test="${curLevel==1}">
    <c:set var="dirMeta" value="${parentNode.metadata}" scope="request" />
    {
           "ishidden":"parentNode.metadata['com.ibm.portal.Hidden']"   //this is working
            "attributes": {
                <% testMeta(pageContext, "dirMeta"); %>
            }
    }
</c:if>
```

In above code, I am passing page identifier from client side fetch the metadata of the page and its children. I am getting object of NavigationNodeBean using `wp.navigationModel` bean.

I am always getting empty Map in the **testMeta** method, the size of **entry1** set is always 0 though there are number of metadata entries present on the page.

Does any one have faced this kind of issue?

Note:
I cannot use  as I am not using the portal's rendering, I am using portal theme with angular, which gets the page content as and when necessary. I am using angular's router to decide which page to render, and in this case portal doesn't have any of the state information about the page I am rendering.

Comment: what is the hidden value coming back as? is that page actually hidden?  one of the things with the metadata beans is that it will traverse up the chain of pages to find what the value will be.  so you may be getting different views.  If in your static method you change to using the metadata service does it actually get values?

Comment: @Crosstalk22 hidden value is coming as false. I will try with metadata services and see if that works. But beans are not working.